# How to use Katalon to insert record into sql database

Tags: katalon

Hi anyone can guide me on how can I insert record into database by using Katalon. I am able to login database in Katalon using custom keyword.

Answer (score 0):

try to use groovy string :

```
insertquery = "INSERT INTO <<TableName>> VALUES ('${email}', '${number}', 'DEV_CH')"
```

Comment: Thank Kishan. 

I have another question.  If I need to create a custom keyword for REST API for GET and POST in Katalon so that I will add into the test case to check for the response

Comment: Hi Kishan how does this multiple insert query work because whenever i run i have met an error

Comment: can you please show your logcat ? or the error part you are getting !!

Comment: Hi Kishan Mevada I have solve it thank you